# Google Analytics track iFrames

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I'm reading through the GA codex and I can't seem to figure out exactly what they are trying to explain.

**The situation:**
I have a site where we do live streaming. Simple pages with a player and chat or a twitter stream. Nothing that complicated. So an example, ClientA orders a live stream I do the following:

```
1. create a client page: domain.com/clientA
    - landingspage with player and twitterstream and such
    - has a GA tracking code
2. domain.com/clientA/ec/
    - a page with only the player for iframe embedding purpose
    - also has a GA tracking code (same, for now)
3. domain.com/ec.php (or whatever)
    - a simple page with the iframe and some explanation
    - this is so they can embed the iFrame on their own site
```

**The Problem**
I can't seem to track when domain.com/clientA/ec/ has been iFramed on a site. So in my understanding the trackingcode on domain.com/clientA and domain.com/clientA/ec/ should differ from each other right?

Iv'e been reading up on [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite?hl=nl#multipleDomains), but no luck so I thought maybe what I want is not possible without having control over the pages hosted on the other sites. Initially I thought it would be no hassle to do so when an embedcode is present on the page that will be iFramed.

So... could anybody explain in non Google english a bit better what is going on here? Don't get me wrong, Google does a pretty good job in codexing their stuff. Sometimes I just can't see the Wood for the Trees.

__
regards, Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracking content that has been iframed on another website aren't going to show you that websites statistics, it is just not how Analytics works.

The thing is, from what I can understand of your setup, is that you want to be able to see if content has been iframed, and see that webpages statistics from the iframed source? Then no, you are out of luck.

The statistics you're seeing are the interactions that has happened on YOUR webpage, where the tracking code is implemented. For you to be able to see anything else other then your webpage, you'd have to have access to those other websites.

What cross-domain tracking does is basically the same thing you are trying to achieve, but it is the "wrong way around". What you usually want to do with cross-domain tracking is to capture data on another domain but retain the visitor information from your own domain. Usually, this involves a shopping website where they have their e-commerce on another servers webpage. You'd then be able to set up the same tracking code on both those domains and then link them together through `setAllowLinker`, `_link`, and other syntaxes that are detailed on the page you [referred](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite?hl=nl#multipleDomains) to.

Comment: Well its not that I want to get that websites statistics but I want to see in my analytics that when an iframe of mine has been framed on a website where it has been iframed and how many visitors it had. The page that is being iframed has the tracking code.

Seems that with the analytics.js (instead of ga.js) it is visible... or just a coincidence due atm I can see when a page of mine is being iframed on a site. It pops up in referrals with the active visitors.  thanks for your detailed explanations... gave me more insight than I had. Thanks!